# I need to add Icon to this Float button dynamically with the shape of this float button

Tags: java, android

[image: Import Problem]
This is my code by the way the Context Compat can not resolve

```
private FloatingActionButton getFAB() {
            FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(this);
            fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.fire));
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    //"insert into Checks (ID,CheckSerail,CheckTitel,CheckType,Covers,MyTable,MyStatus,Splited,RefranceTo,myDateTime,OpenIn,ClosedIn,Cust_ID,Server_ID,Casher_ID,Admin_ID,OutLet_ID,Rest_ID_Active,WS,CreateDate,ModifiedDate,Num_Fired,User_ID,Voided,Voided_Time,Voided_Reason,Order_No,ReOpen,Table_ID,Num_Print,Lvl_Split,ChangeAfterSplit,Combined,Combined_To,ChangeAfterCombine,Received,Received_Time,Point_ID,Meal_ID,Voided_By,Catering_ID,Pick_Up,Pick_Up_Time,Officer) values (@ID,@CheckSerail,@CheckTitel,'DinIn',@Covers,@MyTable,'Open',0,0,GetDate(),@OpenIn,@ClosedIn,@Cust_ID,@Server_ID,@Casher_ID,@Admin_ID,@OutLet_ID,@Rest_ID_Active,@WS,@CreateDate,@ModifiedDate,@Num_Fired,@User_ID,@Voided,@Voided_Time,@Voided_Reason,@Order_No,@ReOpen,@Table_ID,@Num_Print,@Lvl_Split,@ChangeAfterSplit,@Combined,@Combined_To,@ChangeAfterCombine,@Received,@Received_Time,@Point_ID,@Meal_ID,@Voided_By,@Catering_ID,@Pick_Up,@Pick_Up_Time,@Officer)";
                }
            });
            return fab;
        }
```

Comment: Did you add: 1) references to the v4 support library 2) right `import` statment?

Comment: It couldn't be imported as u can see in the pic

Comment: ... *as u can see in the pic* it's because 1) from my previous comment

Comment: Thanks it works well for the ContextCompat by import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat; but I got error with getContext() :D

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on top of Activity class
**import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;**

change **getContext()** to **YourActivityClassName.this**